# What is the method for edge detection of a binary image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection

I have a binary image [0,1]. I want to use Python to find the edge of the image. I have tried sobel method on the binary but it provides a bad result. I expect the output like the image
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way is to apply a 1-pixel morphological erosion, then take the difference between the input image and the result. In pseudo-code:

```
edges = image - erosion(image)
```

Comment: You saved my life. This is code `edges = image - ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation(image)`